# How can I get an integer for the amount of day difference between two dates?

Tags: php

Ok, I've got some code (I think it may be messy and redundant in places - note, it's about the Presidential election, to see which candidate is doing better, hence the Romney's):

```
$romneytime = intval($twitromney["timestamp"]);
$romneydate = date('m/d/Y', $romneytime);
$romlinearray = array();
$romlinearray["date"] = null;
$romlinearray["value"] = null;
$romneydiffobj = date_diff(date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $dateromney),  date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', $romneydate));
$romneydiff = $romneydiffobj->format('%d')

var_dump($romneydiff);
```

For some reason, `var_dump($romneydiff);` isn't putting out any data.

The code should be taking the integer of a time stamp, putting it into date format, and then comparing it with another date, and then outputting the difference of the two dates.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the second last line. Typo or source of problem?

Comment: where do you assign value to $dateromney and why do you search for the difference between the strings and not the integer timestamps? I think it would be way easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime objects and the diff() method to return a DateInterval, then use format to get the difference from the DateInterval

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: And one absolutely has to be converted from a timestamp. That's how it is in the database. The other one I can start off as a DateTime.

Comment: @Andrew - you're passing two date arguments to date_diff, using the procedural style... I'm using OO style, which means I'm creating the time interval from the diff method of one datetime object, passing only the other datetime object as an argument. Using the same methods, but not in the same way